# gcc compile issues for VCGlib

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw32, vcg

i am attempting to build samples of the vcglib project.
there are no makefile but some qmake files.

i have been banging my head trying to build a sample. but gcc is throwing up 100s of errors.

the main error is seems to be

```
#elif defined(__MINGW32__) // GCC
template<class T> int IsNAN(T t) {    return std::isnan(t) || std::isinf(t); 
#elif defined(__GNUC__) // GCC

vcg/math/base.h:197:51: error: expected unqualified-id before '(' token
template<class T> int IsNAN(T t) {    return std::isnan(t) || std::isinf(t);
```

i tried google, and it seems to be related the "define" but i dont understand the issue.

is there makefile someone can throw me?

any help appreciated

thanks

-lp

Comment: `qmake` can generate makefiles

Comment: for the love of mankind, what is the dumb guide to install qmake?. i created an account with QT, then downloaded the installer,..faced with GB of downloads i opted for tools MinGW toolchain... just a guess. 363mb need for download. downloaded failed. i give up... too difficult.